# .htaccess RewriteRule for long URL is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to it. So may be I am doing some silly mistakes. 
In my .htaccess I have written a RewriteRule like below:

```
RewriteRule ^contactus$ /contact.php [L,B]
```

If my url is `http://localhost/contactus` then its working fine.
If my url is `http://localhost/countryname/contactus` then also its working fine.
But when the url is like `http://localhost/songs/Bob+Marley+%26+The+Wailers/One+Love/contactus` then the page is not redirecting

Please Help.

Comment: And where should this url redirect to?

Comment: Its just replacing the last part.

Comment: That is http://localhost/songs/Bob+Marley+%26+The+Wailers/contactus

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question?

Answer (score 0):

The `^` symbol in the beginning of the match means that it should begin matching from the start of the string. This means that your second URL (`http://localhost/countryname/contactus`) should not match either.

If you want to match all URLs ending with "contactus", just remove `^` from the beginning:

```
RewriteRule contactus$ /contact.php [L,B]
```